# Отступ TextView в TableLayout от границ ячейки - как установить Gravity? TextView.setGravity() не срабатывает

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Есть `TableLayout` с одним `Table Row`, в котором есть 2 `TextView`. Нужно чтобы первая `TextView` прижималась к левому краю экрана, а вторая к правому. Как я понял, за это отвечает метод `setGravity(Gravity.LEFT/RIGHT)` или как советует студия `START/END`. Но по какой-то неизвестной причине, они не двигаются. В чём проблема?

```
 TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));




    TextView textview = new TextView(this);
    textview.setText(name1);
    textview.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    textview.setGravity(Gravity.START);
    textview.setTextSize(20);
    tr.addView(textview);


    TextView textview2 = new TextView(this);
    textview2.setText(name2);
    textview2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    textview2.setTextSize(20);
    textview2.setGravity(Gravity.END);

    tr.addView(textview2);

    tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась, стоило всего лишь добавить 2 условия, которые позволяют двигать TextView

```
    tl.setStretchAllColumns(true);
    tl.setShrinkAllColumns(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

В андроиде есть два вида `GRAVITY`:

1. Для внутреннего содержимого `View` (например для прижимания текста `TextView` к низу/верху etc)
2. Для расположения `View` внутри своего родителя (ваш случай).

В `xml` они выглядят так:

1. `android:gravity`
2. `android:layout_gravity`

Программно они тоже назначаются по разному:

1. `View#setGravity(int gravity)` (т.е. то, что вы пытаетесь)
2. Через `LayoutParams` родителя `View` (т.е., если родитель `LinearLayout`, то надо использовать `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`, если же, как у вас, `TableRow`, то `TableRow.LayoutParams`)

   ```
   TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
   textview.setLayoutParams(params);
   ```

Comment: Второй способ не получился, а про первый способ, Вы не ответили, что я делаю не так..

Comment: Может в xml файле следует что-то указать, чтобы программно можно было назначать расположение?